DELTA_SCHEMA_CHANGE_SINCE_ANALYSIS on merging into Delta table, with delete/insert
We are using Azure Databrick for our EDW.
We are experiencing an issue when merging into our delta tables.
We have an extract dataframe (parquet)
extract_df
and a target dataframe (delta)
target_df
There is no primary key on the target table. However all data is loaded in "datastreams", so any changes will always affect a full day and a full datastream
This is what we do
# 1.Find differences
changed_df=extract_df.subtract(target_df)
# 2. Find changed datastreams to update
datastreams_df=changed_df.select("Datastream","Date").distinct()
# 3. Data to be updated
update_df=extract_df.join(datastreams_df,["Datastream","Date"],"Left").withColumn("DwDelete",lit("0"))
#4. Add Data to be deleted
merge_df=update_df.unionByName(datastreams_df.withColumn("DwDelete",lit("0")), allowMissingColumns=True))
# 5. Create view
merge_df.createOrReplaceTempView("v_merge")

%sql
-- Merge
merge into target_table as T using v_merge as S
on S.datastream=T.Datastream
and S.Date=T.Date
and S.DwDelete=1
when matched  and s.DwDelete=1 then delete
when not matched and s.DwDelete=0 then insert *

So in effect I am merging by deleting rows, for datastreams on specific days, and inserting rows on the same days.
We do it by this, becuase that way the delta table is always online. It's a delete/insert update, but since transactions are not present in delta tables, we are doing it like this so user can query the table at all times.
We've had this running for about a year, but in the last couple of months we have begun getting the following error:
[DELTA_SCHEMA_CHANGE_SINCE_ANALYSIS] The schema of your Delta table has changed in an incompatible way since your DataFrame
or DeltaTable object was created. Please redefine your DataFrame or DeltaTable object.
Changes:
Latest schema is missing field(s)

It just appears sometimes, but the next update on the same table will work without errors.
The strange part is that the merge operation has completed, so if I try to rerun the job, no changes are detected! Here is the entry from the history of the Delta table:
sumTargetRowsCopied: "1104"
numTargetRowsDeleted: "422"
numTargetFilesAdded: "1"
numTargetBytesAdded: "88394"
numTargetBytesRemoved: "80025"
numTargetDeletionVectorsAdded: "0"
numTargetRowsMatchedUpdated: "0"
executionTimeMs: "22335"
materializeSourceTimeMs: "17218"
numTargetRowsInserted: "672"
numTargetRowsMatchedDeleted: "422"
numTargetDeletionVectorsUpdated: "0"
scanTimeMs: "1806"
numTargetRowsUpdated: "0"
numOutputRows: "1776"
numTargetDeletionVectorsRemoved: "0"
numTargetRowsNotMatchedBySourceUpdated: "0"
numTargetChangeFilesAdded: "0"
numSourceRows: "758"
numTargetFilesRemoved: "1"
numTargetRowsNotMatchedBySourceDeleted: "0"
rewriteTimeMs: "3201"

We are running on 14.3 LTS
The delta tables are served on serverless Synapse SQL, so we have set
"Auto-Enable Deletion Vectors" DISABLED

Since serverless SQL cannot read this version of delta tables.
My best guess is that the error comes because it's trying to delete and insert similar rows, however that doesnøt explain why it's not a consistent error message, and why the transaction completes successfully with the expected result even though we get the error!

It is due to schema change while writing and reading the data simultaneously.  use target_df = DeltaTable.forName(spark, "target_table") with target_df.toDF() before every merge so that every time schema is refreshed

Add sample data of target_df and extract_df.

There are two possible reasons:
Solution 1: The Delta table(target table) might be out of sync. So run the below code.
spark.catalog.refreshTable("target_table")

Solution 2:
For minor schema adjustments, in your MERGE logic at the end add the below code:
OPTIONS (mergeSchema = 'true')

Hope these will resolve the issue of one time successful and the other time error.
